# Default click "I have read and agree to the website terms and conditions"

Tags: functions

On WordPress checkout page, I want to make the "I have read and agree to the website terms and conditions" default clicked. Users can unclick the check icon. Is there any code available?

[image]

Comment: There is a template for that you can override, [terms.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/terms.php). Just make sure to not edit the core woocommerece files, you would need to create a override, they explain in the comments

Comment: Hi @Buttered_Toast, can't it be done via functions?

Comment: WordPress doesn't have a checkout. Are you using a plugin? Presumably WooCommerce. Please note that while @Buttered_Toast and Zeshan were kind enough to give you information, third party plugins such as WooCommerce are off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet in functions.php for your child theme

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_terms_is_checked_default', '__return_true' );
```